# When Natlink is enabled Dragon freezes

Tags: speech-recognition, naturallyspeaking

When Natlink is enabled Dragon freezes and wont fully boot. I used [this](http://qh.antenna.nl/unimacro/installation/installation.html) natlink download. And followed the directions on the site. Any incite to why this is happening is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a file called "Dragon.log" created by Dragon, which may have useful debugging information. I'm having the same problem as you, and am in the process of going through it.

Comment: Which version of Dragon NaturallySpeaking do you use?